# The type generates a string that requires more than 65535 bytes to encode in Utf8 format in the constant pool

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying out antlr4 with a somewhat large grammar that worked in antlr3.  Worked through 2 grammar changes needed and now I have the tool producing the lexer and parser.

However, the lexer has a compile error:

> 1) The type generates a string that requires more than 65535 bytes to
>   encode in Utf8 format in the constant pool

The error shows up in Eclipse on the class name, so not sure exactly which string it is talking about, but I suspect it is this very long String:

```
    public static final String _serializedATN =
        "\1\2\u01c5\u1741\6\uffff\2\0\7\0\2\1\7\1\2\2\7\2\2\3\7\3\2\4\7\4\2\5\7"+
        "\5\2\6\7\6\2\7\7\7\2\b\7\b\2\t\7\t\2\n\7\n\2\13\7\13\2\f\7\f\2\r\7\r\2"+
... etc, etc (few hundred lines of unicode)
```

Looks like a bug in the parser generator, but possible there is some new setting required for antlr4 I'm not aware of (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a limitation in Java, not a bug in ANTLR (the correct serialization string is created, but Java's encoding can't store it). Last week we [tweaked the `_serializedATN`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/133) representation to help with this problem, but we have not implemented a complete workaround involving breaking the serialized form into multiple strings or allowing its storage in a separate file loaded at runtime.

There may be some ways to tweak the grammar to reduce the size of the required ATN, but I would need to see the grammar to evaluate that.

**Update:** Starting with ANTLR 4.1, `_serializedATN` is now split as necessary to ensure the constant pool limit is not exceeded in the generated code. See [issue 76](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/76) for details.